# Crusade of vs. Crusades for - which is correct?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

> **Crusade of** or **crusade for**
>
> **Crusades of** or **crusades for**

Which expression is correct? Also, do any express the party the crusade against?

For example, is "crusade *for* peace against dictators" the correct term to express that people against dictators so that the people may have peace?

Comment: Include the question in the body, apart from mentioning it in the title.

Answer (score 3):

All the three are possible options depending on the actual sentence.

The *crusades **of*** (by whom)/ (when);
The *crusades **for*** (a cause)/ (on behalf of);
The *crusades **against*** (whom or what).

"The crusade of fire/ crusade of destiny/ crusade of prayer …"
"The crusade for freedom/ peace/ art. …"
"The crusade against hunger/ cancer/ corruption. …"

Comment: Thank you Kris. So the form of the noun "crusade" depends on the countability of the object, right?

Comment: Plus, it can have the meaning of "looking for", right? Like when people try to look for the losing peace, can I say "crusade of losing peace"? I assumed I can't say "for", which means I want "losing peace".

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard the expression "crusade *of*" anything, but if I did, I would think the something would be the *participants* in the crusade.  There could be a crusade of mothers against liquor, for example.

"Crusade for peace against dictators" may be technically correct, but wordy and awkward. 
"Crusade for peace and against dictators" would be less awkward but even wordier.

Comment: We do not want any peace for the dictators

Answer (score 1):

There is another option for "crusade of" and that is - what the crusade will entail. "It will be a crusade of terror and violence."

Comment: Great, so "a crusade of questions" is "a crusade for answers"?

Comment: Yes. That's the way I see it anyway.